# Configuración de PHP para Apache en Windows

Tags: php, apache, curl

Buenos días. Estoy tratando de configurar PHP para Apache en Windows. He conseguido que Apache lea correctamente los ficheros PHP, pero algo falla en la configuración, ya que no me carga ningun modulo PHP correctamente.

Los pasos que segui fueron:

1. Descargo y descomprimo PHP y lo guardo en el directorio C:
2. Copio PHP-ini-production del directorio php a C:\Windows y lo renombro con el nombre php.ini.
3. Dentro del fichero php.ini cambio la directiva extension_dir = "ext" por extension_dir = "c:\php\ext".
4. Cambio la directiva session.save_path a  c:\temp
5. Dado que necesito la extension curl de PHP, descomento la siguiente linea:
   extension=php_curl.dll
6. Dentro de httpd.conf añado el siguiente fragmento:
   LoadModule php7_module "c:/php/php7apache2_4.dll"
   AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
   PHPIniDir "c:/windows"

Esto, como he dicho antes, reconoce PHP correctamente, pero si abro un phpinfo veo que la directiva Loaded Configuration File aparece vacía, y los módulos no se activan.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si me permites la sugerencia, para correr apache y php en windows, te recomiendo [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), la gestión se vuelve mucho más sencilla, y activar/desactivar o instalar extensiones y módulos se vuelve trivial.

Comment: Lo tuve en cuenta en un primer momento, pero la situación en la que me encuentro requiere de una instalación limpia de Apache+PHP.

Comment: ¿ Si intentas ejecutar algún script desde _cli_ te muestra algún error ?

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es  PHPIniDir "c:/windows" de tener es la ruta de donde tienes el php.

PHPIniDir "c:/php"

Saludos.